# I have a plsql procedure which gives a table type output. I need to get all the rows in json format using a select statement but it is returning null

Tags: sql, plsql

This is what I tried.
I have a plsql procedure that gives a table type output. So I created a plsql function to call the procedure and convert the output to a clob (tried VARCHAR2 as well) which contains the json formatted table rows. I tested the function using a plsql script and it is returning the expected result but when I'm trying to call the function using a select statement, I'm getting a null value every time. Please help.

Procedure signature is like `procedure(p1 IN, p2 IN, ..., x OUT table)`
Function is like

```
func(p1 IN, p2 IN, ... ) return CLOB 
AS res CLOB;
   t table;
BEGIN
proc(p1, p2,....,t)
    FOR cursor1 IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(t AS table)))
          LOOP
           
            res := res || '{ ' || 
                        '"column1" : ' || '"' || cursor1.column1 || '"' || ',' ||
                        '"column2" : ' || '"' || cursor1.column2 || '"' || ',' ||
                        '"column3" : ' || '"' || cursor1.column3 || '"' || ',' ||
                        '"column4" : ' || '"' || cursor1.column4 || '"' || ',' ||
                    '}' || ',';               
            
          END LOOP;
    return res;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [json objects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.html#GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE) of oracle?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I modified the function to return the JSON object as VARCHAR2. The function is working as expected. But I'm still getting null when I call the function from the select statement.